# .Net Hosting (Flexible Medium Trust)

Tags: .net, hosting, medium-trust

Any recommendations for cheap .Net hosting that has flexible medium trust rules allowing the use of reflection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **[GoDaddy Hosting](http://www.godaddy.com)** ([info](http://www.bizshark.com/company/godaddy.com)) - Really cheap, $5/month. And the most popular.
- **[DiscountASP.NET](http://www.discountasp.net)** ([info](http://www.bizshark.com/company/discountasp.net)) - More expansive, starting from $10/month+. The good thing is that they are specializing on .NET
- **[SoftSys Hosting](http://www.softsyshosting.com/)** - Small company. But they are more flexible. They are also specializing in Windows Hosting solutions.

Comment: Godaddy allow reflection? Not sure it does?

Comment: If you like, I can upload your testing page and we'll see. You can also ask this question at http://help.godaddy.com

Comment: Godaddy is medium trust, which means that u can't use stuff like IL emit(Nhibernate needs this for proxying)

Answer (score 2):

[www.gearhost.com](http://www.gearhost.com) gives you 100 free .NET, PHP sites and MSSQL or MySQL databases with full trust for free, no credit card needed. Perfect during development then scale to paid ($5) when your ready. Full cloud environment with high availability and load balancing on all apps.

Answer (score 0):

Register.com is a good site to